# Choose select statement to use based on condition in with clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to choose a select to use based on a boolean condition in Oracle. I have to do this in a With clause.

I tried and noticed that i have to start with a select statement in the with clause or else i get an error. Meaning i cannot do something like:

```
with variable_1 as (  
 select * from tableA

), variable_2 as(
if (true) then
  begin
   select * from tableB 
  end if;
 end;
if (false) then   
 begin
   select * from tableC 
 end if;
end;
)
select  v1.name, v2.surname
from variable_1 v1, variable_2 v2;
```

I want to achieve the condition below:

```
with variable_1 as (  
  select * from tableA

), variable_2 as(

 --If condition is true select from tableB as below
  select * from tableB 

 --If condition is false select from tableC as below  
    select * from tableC

)

select  v1.name, v2.surname
from variable_1 v1, variable_2 v2;
```

If condition is true then we should select from tableB only and not use tableC 
AND
If condition is false then we should select from tableC only and not use tableB

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: @OldProgrammer is there a work around?

Comment: @Etch - you **can** do that, easily - I just showed how in an Answer.

Comment: @mathguy i used union all but the reason why i removed union all is that i did not want to run two select statements to optimize the code. I want to run at one select based on condition because in reality it a big select query

Comment: Please show this *boolean condition* (which must be based on some source) and *big select query* (possible soruce). Likely there is a compact, DRY way to do this. Without these specifics, we are shooting blanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you show as the "desired behavior", using `select *` for tables `B` and `C`, is only possible if both tables have the same columns (meaning: same number of columns, of the same data types, in the same order - and any reference to column names will follow table `B` names, if the column names are not the same in the two tables).

If this is not true, you can change the `select` to just select common columns. For example, in the outer select you only use `surname`, so perhaps you only need to select that one column from either table.

With that said: you can do it like so

```
...
variable_2 as (
  select surname from tableB WHERE <YOUR_CONDITION> -- meaning, where it is TRUE
  UNION ALL
  select surname from tableC WHERE <NOT YOUR_CONDITION>
```

If needed (for something else perhaps), you can also use `select *` from both tables, but only if the conditions in my first paragraph (above) are met.

Comment: The reason why i did not use a union all is that i did not want to run two select statements to optimise the code.

Comment: @Etch - Oracle will evaluate the `WHERE` condition for access - it won't touch the table you don't need. Experiment with it and you'll see.

Comment: because it is a union the table tableC will be definately queried and i wanted to avoid that because in reality it a big select query. So it would be best to run just one query based on condition

Comment: @Etch if the condition is guaranteed to be false for all rows for that union branch, the database _won't access that table_. For an example, see https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=selection-from-union-view-by-table-identifier

Comment: `I did not want to run two select statements`... you either have to repeat the entire query, or one of your subqueries. Unless you want to go down the rocky road of dynamic SQL, but I wouldn't do that in this situation. Static SQL is by far easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: @mathguy - it seems your solution was the best i could get. I went with that. Thanks!